# The usage of "if" in sentences that deal with what is possible to happen in the future

Tags: future, simple-past

I recently came up with a problem to form sentences with a particular structure. I thought that I already knew how to form such sentences subconsciously, but by listening to native speakers conversations and also getting more detailed in my own usage of words, I'm suspecting whether this unconscious feeling is true.
The question is this: If we want to talk to the second person pronoun (you) about an event that is likely to happen in the future and we want to suggest him what to do in case it happens, how must we say the first part (the if part) of our sentence, present or past? For example:
1) If you found the problem difficult to solve, simply skip it and go to the next question.
2) If you've found the problem difficult, simply skip it and go to the next question.
3) If you find the problem difficult to solve, simply skip it and go to the next question.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer**

*3) If you find the problem difficult to solve, simply skip it and go to the next question.*

When talking about the future with 'if' we use the present tense.

**Explicit examples**

*If in future you find the problem difficult to solve, simply skip it and go to the next question.*

*If tomorrow you find the problem difficult to solve, simply skip it and go to the next question.*

*If during the exam you find the problem difficult to solve, simply skip it and go to the next question.*

Comment: Thank you, from this moment on I think that I'd better change the structure I have been using in almost all my conversations!

Answer (score 1):

For hypotheticals we we can use present tense:

> If **you run** into Amir, tell him I say "hi."
>
> If **the lion escapes**, you had better catch it!
>
> If **the zombies attack**, tell my mother I love her.

Take a look at the highlighted portions of each sentence,

> You run, the lion escapes, the zombies attack

are all present tense conjugations of these verbs.

Comment: Thank you, I think that I have fully found the answer I had been seeking for days.

Answer (score -1):

2 and 3 are acceptable to my AmE ear.  The past tense in 1 sounds wrong to me.  To me, #1 refers to a past situation. I'd say "If you found the problem difficult (yesterday, when you were taking the test), you should have skipped it."

Comment: I have a question: How and in which case would you use the second sentence (i.e: If you've found ...)? Can it be used interchangeably instead of the 3rd sentence or do they differ in some senses from each other?

Comment: @Amir Ahmad Ezhieh: One could advise a prospective test taker: "If, while you're taking the test, you've found a particular question to be unclear, skip it and move on."  The nuance of the perfect is that the test-taker is imagined to be in the midst of taking the test and to have encountered a question he should skip.

Answer (score -2):

2) is not good, but both 1) and 3) are okay.  The difference between 1) and 3) is whether you take the perspective of your advisee before he has started the exam (then you use 3)) or as he is doing the exam and has already read through the problem (then you use 1)).  After he has read the problem, but before he tries to solve it, the event of him finding it difficult lies in the past from that future time.  So "found" makes sense, if you are putting yourself in his place, and "walking him through" the process.